# php assumes string/int a false on certain condition

Tags: php

While in project I have to check a variable for a condition.Lets say variable is $key and the 
$condition is true

```
$key = ($condition)?$key+1:'no'

if($key!='no') //evaluated false
```

I cant set $key to false because at some point it becomes 0 so at that time php will execute it false. 
but when I did this

```
$key = ($condition)?$key+1:78857555555555
```

Then checking with

```
if($key!=78857555555555)
```

evaluated true

Why?  Does it problem like $key is an int and I'm assigning it to a string in first one above. I didn't try type  casting. As it will increase two or three lines.

P. S: Sorry,  I misinterpreted the problem.  It was problem of checking object type so putting an extra = solved it.

Comment: please use operator === !== so it also check type of object. for example: if($key !== 78857555555555)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `!==`. It will check the type as well.

> But all evaluated false I cant set $key to false because at some point it becomes 0 so at that time php will execute it false. but when I did this

You can set the $key to false.

```
$key = 0;
var_dump($key !== false);  // true
var_dump($key != false);   // false
```

Comment: I answered faster :) +1

Comment: @Yair.R, yeah, you answered faster :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue here:

```
(null!=null) will obviously evaluate to false
isset(null) does evaluate to false according to the documentation
($key!='no') also will evaluate to false, obviously
```

This is all plausible to me...